# Which words could be used in accounting or bookkeeping email addresses?

Tags: email

I need to select all the accounting or bookkeeping email addresses out of a big list.
According to the task, the ones that contain the words "sales" or "production" are not accounting.
I filtered all that look like `accounting@company.com`, and the ones that contain the word "account".
But there should be more.
My patron may expect I should have enough English knowledge to know what words belong to the matter, without re-asking him for details, and I don't want to disappoint him.
Here are the examples of emails I found on the Internet, could anyone point which of them belong to the accounting or bookkeeping category?

```
admin@  
answers@  
billing@ 
book@  
comments@   
contact@   
customer@  
data@ 
everyone@  
general@  
home@  
info@  
manager@  
office@  
orders@  
press@  
privacy@  
reception@  
registrar@  
secretary@  
service@  
staff@  
subscribe@  
recipient@  
welcome@
```

Any other words?

Comment: office is a good one too

Comment: Yes, **office** gave me a dozen more addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native British English speaker, I would not say any of the words you have listed are exclusively associated with accounting. **billing** may be, but it *could* also be part of the sales department which you have rejected.

I suggest that you Google "synonyms for accounting". The only extra word I could find doing this was **finance**

Comment: You should add **office** too